# Why is my ternary operator breaking my login routees?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm practicing fundamentals by creating a basic authentication using PERN. My user auth routes are working on the front- and back-end. Logging in and out with JWT functionality works, but when I try to set up a ternary operator that will remember the user's authorization status even when you click to another page, it breaks everything. Here's the code for my client entry point.

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import './App.css';

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

//components
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Register from "./components/Register";


function App() {
  async function isAuth() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/v1/auth/verify/", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: { jwt_token : localStorage.token }
      }); 

      const parseRes = await response.json();
      //parseRes === true ? setIsAuthenticated(true) : 
      //setIsAuthenticated(false);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    isAuth()
  })

    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  const setAuth = boolean => {
    setIsAuthenticated(boolean);
  };

    return (
    <Fragment>
      <Router>
        <div className="container">
          <Switch>
            <Route
              exact
              path="/login"
              render={props =>
                !isAuthenticated ? (
                  <Login {...props} setAuth={setAuth} />
                ) : (
                  <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
                )
              }
            />
            <Route
              exact
              path="/register"
              render={props =>
                !isAuthenticated ? (
                  <Register {...props} setAuth={setAuth} />
                ) : (
                  <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
                )
              }
            />
            <Route
              exact
              path="/dashboard"
              render={props =>
                isAuthenticated ? (
                  <Dashboard {...props} setAuth={setAuth} />
                ) : (
                  <Redirect to="/login" />
                )
              }
            />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and this is the code for my back-end dashboard routes, where I think the miscommunication may be happening? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const db = require("../db");
const authorization = require('../middleware/authorization');

router.get("/", authorization, async(req, res) => {
    try {
        // req.user comes from authorization, contains jwt payload
        const user = await db.query("SELECT user_name, user_email FROM users WHERE user_id = $1", [req.user]);
        res.json(user.rows[0]);
    } catch (err) {
        console.err(err.message)
        res.status(500).json("Server Error");
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Its not clear at all what the issue is you are having, what do you mean by "breaks everything" what doesn't work? and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: I don't think `localStorage.token` would work, instead can you try using `localStorage.getItem('token')`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the confusion! I realized I didn't leave enough information, but I also traced down the source of the issue almost immediately after posting. It was a simple issue with the token variable being mislabeled.

Comment: you can add the solution to your question. someday it may helpful to someone that has the same question